# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object using Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, miniconda

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "C:\Users\rafin\Dyna\updews-pycodes\dynadb\db.py", line 251, in read
    db, cur = connect(host=host, connection=connection,
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object
```

[Here](https://products.groupdocs.app/editor/wysiwyg/Textual/59898d83-658e-4500-b170-ace7dcfed70f) is the whole db.py script which is the source of the TypeError if it helps

Please tell me if there's any additional information that I could provide.

Comment: You should post the minimal amount of code to produce the error message you're seeing.

Comment: The link in your question has the formatting all messed up. Please put the snippet of the actual code here.

Comment: This is a symptom of a software design problem. It looks like the `connect` function can return different types of things in different situations. Here, your code is expecting a tuple of two items, but is getting a bool back instead. the syntax `x, y` means "unpack" into two local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error comes from doing the equivalent of the following:

```
x, y = True

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object
```

On the right-hand side of the assignment, you have a boolean, `True`. The interpreter has no way to split that up into 2 values as required by the left-hand side of the assignment, so it gives an error.

Your `connect` function returns a Connection object and a Cursor cursor object when connection succeeds, but returns the boolean value False when connection fails, leading you to the above error.

It's generally considered a design problem to return different shapes of results from a function. Raise an exception on failure or return the same shape on all code paths, say (True, connection, cursor) on success and (False, None, None) on failure.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Can you explain this to me like I'm five? I'm unfortunately new to python. So you mean the error is in the 'db.py' file and the line ```db, cur = connect(host=host, connection=connection,```?

Comment: Where does the connect function come from? And could it be returning a boolean rather than a pair of values?

Comment: Try `x = connect(host=host, connection=connection, ...` and `print(type(x))`. That will tell you what type of value you're getting back.

Comment: Here is the full script producing the error if it helps: https://products.groupdocs.app/editor/wysiwyg/Textual/59898d83-658e-4500-b170-ace7dcfed70f

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the `connect` function returns False when it fails to connect: 

if dbc:
    return get_connector(dbc=dbc, conn_type=conn_type)
else:
    print ('Cannot Connect to Database Connection')
    return False

Comment: Looks like that code is trying to access a MySQL database running on your local machine. If already have that set up, great, but if not that's what you need. Probably more than can be worked out here. You'll need help closer to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Still don't know how to solve the problem but at least I now understand where it went wrong.